# Set default value of replace-string in Emacs by selecting a word

Tags: emacs, replace

I'm using function like this to replace strings in Emacs.

```
(defun replace-string-from-top ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (call-interactively 'replace-string)))
(global-set-key "\C-r" 'replace-string-from-top)
```

And I want to use default value of replace-string function by selecting a word.

What I want to do is.

1. select a word by double clicking it.
2. call `replace-string-from-top` function with the selected word by default value.

I've tried to write the function but I couldn't.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `replace-string` nor the function that it uses to read its args when you call it interactively, which is `query-replace-read-args`, has any provision for providing a default programmatically in a dynamic way.  The most you can do is set variable `query-replace-defaults`.  You can bind that variable to a value in your command, so that the first element in its list value is the string from the region, i.e.:

```
 (let* ((region-string           (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
        (query-replace-defaults  (cons region-string region-string)))
   ...)
```

(The value is a cons.  Use whatever other value you like as the `cdr`.  Here I've just used the same region string.)

But you can more easily and more directly do what you want if you use library [`replace+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/replace%2b.el). In that case, just set option `search/replace-region-as-default-flag` to non-`nil` to get what you want.  You can also toggle that option anytime, using command `toggle-search/replace-region-as-default`. A description of the library is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/ReplacePlus).

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I'm going to use `replace+.el', but that is not works as I expected. After installing I put in my init file `(require 'replace+)(setq search/replace-region-as-default-flag t)` and eval it, and select a word and call function `query-replace-w-option`, but the default value is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By "empty" just what do you mean? There is nothing in the minibuffer by default -- that would be an "initial" value, not a "default" value. To get the default value you use `M-n`, as always in Emacs. If you do not get the selected text in the minibuffer after you use `M-n` then that is a bug -- let me know.

Comment: I misunderstood the words "initial value" and "default value". What I want is to set a "initial" value without typing `M-n`. I've searched in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplacePlus with the word "initial" but I couldn't find any information. How can I set initial value?

Comment: Emacs Dev discourages the use of initial values. However, you could replace the 5th arg to `completing-read` and the 2nd arg to `read-from-minibuffer` with `default` (instead of `nil`), in the `replace+.el` definition of `query-replace-read-from`, to get the effect you want. Or you could just use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) and customize option `icicle-default-value` so that the default value is ***always*** used as an initial value (i.e., inserted in the minibuffer). I do that myself, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I've straggled 30 minutes long to use `icicles`, but it doesn't work. I've `git clone` from here https://github.com/emacsmirror/icicles and load it and put my init file `(require 'icicles)(setq icicle-default-value t)
(setq icicle-default-in-prompt-format-function t)`. I'm reading a wiki page EmacsWiki: Icicles - Customization and General Tips
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips

Comment: Sorry for your trouble. You can follow up using email if you like, but you will need to try to help yourself by reading some of the doc. First, do `C-h v` for each of those variables. You'll see that (a) you do *not* want `t` for `icicle-default-value`, since that does *not* insert the default value in the minibuffer. And so (b) you do not want to use the second variable at all (since it has no effect unless the first is `t`. I recommend you start with the beginning of the Icicles doc, in particular, the `Nutshell View` section.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my setup. You can change it in a few places, like add `beginning-of-buffer`, if you want.

```
(defvar qr-beg)

(defun string-dwim ()
  (let ((bounds
         (if (region-active-p)
             (cons (region-beginning)
                   (region-end))
           (ignore-errors
             (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))))
    (setq qr-beg (car bounds))
    (when (region-active-p)
      (set-mark nil))
    (when qr-beg
      (kill-new
       (buffer-substring-no-properties
        qr-beg
        (cdr bounds))))))

(defun query-replace-dwim (from)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-regexp "Query replace" (string-dwim))))
  (when qr-beg
    (goto-char qr-beg)
    (setq qr-beg))
  (query-replace
   from
   (query-replace-read-to from "Query replace" nil)))
```

As you can see, this is a setup for `query-replace`.
It auto-suggests the thing to be replaced as the current string.
The current string is either the current region, if it's active, or symbol at point.
Also, the current string is `kill-new`ed, so you can yank it as the replacement,
and then just tweak it a bit.